# jQuery - How to add "Thank you" message after embedded Mailchimp form email submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mailchimp, email-validation

I have a simple Mailchimp form embedded on a landing page and I'm trying to get a success message ("Thank you!") to return after the user inserts their email address. Is there a simple function using jQuery that would make this work? I'd also like to stop Mailchimp from opening a redirect success page.

Here's what I have right now.

```js
$(function(){
  $(".success-msg").hide();
  $(".signup").on("click", function(){
      $(this).next(".success-msg").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="newsletter-module" id="mc_embed_signup">
  <a href="#" class="news-show"><p>Join mailing list</p></a>
  <!-- MC SIGNUP FORM -->
  <form class="signup validate" action="mailchimp-link-here" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" onsubmit="return Validate()">
      <span class="newsletter-input-wrapper mc-field-group">
          <input class="input-text required email" id="mce-EMAIL" type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
      </span>
      <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_f2d244c0df42a0431bd08ddea_aeaa9dd034" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
      <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
          <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
          <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
      </div>
      <label>
          <input type="submit" name="subscribe" value="Sign Up" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
      </label>
      <div id="success-msg"><p>Thank you!</p></div>
  </form>
</div> <!-- .newsletter-module -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out https://jsfiddle.net/hxrzwv63/

```js
$(function(){
  $("#success-msg").hide();
  $(".button").on("click", function(){
      $("#success-msg").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="newsletter-module" id="mc_embed_signup">
  <a href="#" class="news-show"><p>Join mailing list</p></a>
  <!-- MC SIGNUP FORM -->
  <form class="signup validate" action="mailchimp-link-here" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" onsubmit="return Validate()">
      <span class="newsletter-input-wrapper mc-field-group">
          <input class="input-text required email" id="mce-EMAIL" type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
      </span>
      <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_f2d244c0df42a0431bd08ddea_aeaa9dd034" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
      <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
          <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
          <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
      </div>
      <label>
          <input type="button" name="subscribe" value="Sign Up" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
      </label>
      <div id="success-msg"><p>Thank you!</p></div>
  </form>
</div> <!-- .newsletter-module -->
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Is it possible to also stop Mailchimp from opening the redirect success page in this function?